# jOOQ: fetch into Map<K, List<Record2<V,W>>

Tags: java, jooq

**Abstract query**

```
select A.*, B.*, C.*
from A
left join B on B.aId = A.aId
left join C on C.cId = B.cId
```

**Idea**
I want to fetch this into some object, which is grouped by A (each B has a unique C connected to it). For me the most logical type of object to fetch into, would be something like Map<A, List<Record2<B,C>>.

**Code**
I tried something like

```
using(configuration()).select(A.fields())
        .select(B.fields())
        .select(C.fields())
        .from(A)
        .leftJoin(B).on(B.aId.eq(A.aId)
        .leftJoin(C).on(C.cId.eq(B.cId)
        .fetchGroups(
            r -> r.into(A).into(APojo.class),
            r -> r.into(B).into(BPojo.class),
            r -> r.into(C).into(CPojo.class)); // Goes wrong because fetchGroups only accepts 2 arguments
```

**Background of solution**
I don't want to use fetch(), because all the records would contain duplicate data of A, which I want to avoid. I am converting it to a JSON object, where A would contain a list of B's and in which B contains the object C. To get this structure, Map<A, List<Result2<B,C>> would be perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to manually group those `<B, C>` types into some data structure, e.g. jOOλ's [`Tuple2` type](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/lambda/tuple/Tuple2.html)  or also [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)

```java
Map<APojo, List<Tuple<BPojo, CPojo>>> result =
using(configuration()).select(A.fields())
        .select(B.fields())
        .select(C.fields())
        .from(A)
        .leftJoin(B).on(B.aId.eq(A.aId))
        .leftJoin(C).on(C.cId.eq(B.cId))
        .fetchGroups(
            r -> r.into(A).into(APojo.class),
            r -> tuple(
                     r.into(B).into(BPojo.class),
                     r.into(C).into(CPojo.class)));
```

An alternative would be to resort to using streams and nested maps:

```java
Map<APojo, Map<BPojo, CPojo>> result =
using(configuration()).select(A.fields())
        .select(B.fields())
        .select(C.fields())
        .from(A)
        .leftJoin(B).on(B.aId.eq(A.aId))
        .leftJoin(C).on(C.cId.eq(B.cId))
        .fetch()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            r -> r.into(A).into(APojo.class),
            Collectors.toMap(
                r -> r.into(B).into(BPojo.class),
                r -> r.into(C).into(CPojo.class))));
```

[jOOQ 3.11 will include a `ResultQuery.collect()` method](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7469), so the `fetchStream()` call can be omitted:

```java
Map<APojo, Map<BPojo, CPojo>> result =
using(configuration()).select(A.fields())
        .select(B.fields())
        .select(C.fields())
        .from(A)
        .leftJoin(B).on(B.aId.eq(A.aId))
        .leftJoin(C).on(C.cId.eq(B.cId))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            r -> r.into(A).into(APojo.class),
            Collectors.toMap(
                r -> r.into(B).into(BPojo.class),
                r -> r.into(C).into(CPojo.class))));
```

Comment: I have a multiple ManyToOne relations. Is there any way to place List<CPojo> inside BPojo and List<BPojo> inside APojo automatically?