# How to Fetch Multiple Level One to many Nesting with Jooq

Tags: java, sql, spring, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

Here is the Scenario, I have 5 tables having one to many relations with each other, I have to map result data in hierarchical manner in below given Pojos with Jooq.

DB Tables are a, b, c, d, e

```
// Here are response Pojo's
Class APojo {
  public string name;
  public List<BPojo> listOfB;

}

Class BPojo {
  public string name;
  public List<CPojo> listOfC;
}

Class CPojo {
  public string name;
  public List<DPojo> listOfD;

}

Class DPojo {
  public string name;
  public List<EPojo> listOfE;

}

Class EPojo {
  public string name;

}
```

**Expected sample response**

```
{
  "name":"A1",
  "list_of_b":[
    {
      "name":"A1B1",
      "list_of_c":[
        {
          "name":"A1B1C1",
          "list_of_d":[
            {
              "name":"A1B1C1D1",
              "list_of_e":[
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D1E1"
                },
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D1E2"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"A1B1C1D2",
              "list_of_e":[
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D2E1"
                },
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D2E2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name":"A1B1C2",
          "list_of_d":[
            {
              "name":"A1B1C2D1",
              "list_of_e":[
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C2D1E1"
                },
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C2D1E2"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"A1B1C2D2",
              "list_of_e":[
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C2D2E1"
                },
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C2D2E2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"A1B2",
      "list_of_c":[
        {
          "name":"A1B2C1",
          "list_of_d":[
            {
              "name":"A1B2C1D1",
              "list_of_e":[
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D1"
                },
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D2"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"A1B2C1D2",
              "list_of_e":[
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D1"
                },
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name":"A1B2C2",
          "list_of_d":[
            {
              "name":"A1B2C2D1",
              "list_of_e":[
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D1"
                },
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D2"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"A1B2C2D2",
              "list_of_e":[
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D1"
                },
                {
                  "name":"A1B1C1D2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried something like this first but It did not work because fetch groups only accepts 2 arguments

```
using(configuration()).select(A.fields())
    .select(B.fields())
    .select(C.fields())
    .select(D.fields())
    .select(E.fields())
    .from(A)
    .join(B).on(A.ID.eq(B.A_ID)
    .join(C).on(B.ID.eq(C.B_ID)
    .join(D).on(C.ID.eq(D.C_ID)
    .join(E).on(D.ID.eq(E.D_ID)
    .fetchGroups(
        r -> r.into(A).into(APojo.class),
        r -> r.into(B).into(BPojo.class),
        r -> r.into(C).into(CPojo.class),
        r -> r.into(D).into(DPojo.class),
        r -> r.into(E).into(EPojo.class)
     );
```

[Then I got this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192902/jooq-fetch-into-mapk-listrecord2v-w) and tried it as given below and other 2 method given in the post, but this also did not worked because `Collectors.toMap` accepts only 2 arguments and I have to fetch 5 level hierarchical data.

```
using(configuration()).select(A.fields())
        .select(B.fields())
        .select(C.fields())
        .select(D.fields())
        .select(E.fields())
        .from(A)
        .join(B).on(A.ID.eq(B.A_ID)
        .join(C).on(B.ID.eq(C.B_ID)
        .join(D).on(C.ID.eq(D.C_ID)
        .join(E).on(D.ID.eq(E.D_ID)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            r -> r.into(A).into(APojo.class),
            Collectors.toMap(
                r -> r.into(B).into(BPojo.class),
                r -> r.into(C).into(CPojo.class)
                r -> r.into(D).into(DPojo.class)
                r -> r.into(E).into(EPojo.class)
 )));
```

Comment: Do you ultimately need POJO or JSON output? What database product are you using?

Comment: @LukasEder I need the response to be mapped to POJO's first and finally the api endpoint should respond with JSON. I am using PostgreSQL Database

Answer (score 5):

#### The `JOIN` approach

Historically, most ORMs attempted to nest collections in some way using joins, since joins have been the only widely supported way of "connecting" collections (but not nesting them) in SQL. The result is a flat, denormalised table, that is hard to normalise again. There are a lot of duplicates, and possibly even unwanted cartesian products, and it might not even be possible to be sure what nested collection belongs to a parent value. In your case, it would be possible, but very wasteful both on the server and on the client. The values of `A` would be repeated many many times.

Some workarounds have been implemented, including by third parties (for jOOQ). Alternatives include running several queries and connecting the values afterwards. All of them very tedious.

Luckily, jOOQ 3.14+ offers support for nesting collections out of the box!

#### A jOOQ 3.14 approach using SQL/JSON

[The jOOQ 3.14 appraoch to nesting collections is using SQL/JSON](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/10/09/nesting-collections-with-jooq-3-14s-sql-xml-or-sql-json-support/) behind the scenes (or SQL/XML, but in your case, JSON seems more appropriate).

From your question, I don't see why you need the POJO intermediate step, so perhaps you can bypass that and generate the JSON directly in the database. If not, see below.

Write this query:

```java
ctx
  .select(
    // Optionally, wrap this level in jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject()) too, like the others
    A.NAME,
    field(
      select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
        key("name").value(B.NAME),
        key("list_of_c").value(
          select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
            key("name").value(C.NAME),
            key("list_of_d").value(
              select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
                key("name").value(D.NAME),
                key("list_of_e").value(
                  select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(key("name").value(E.NAME))))
                  .from(E)
                  .where(E.D_ID.eq(D.ID))
                )
              )))
              .from(D)
              .where(D.C_ID.eq(C.ID))
            )
          )))
          .from(C)
          .where(C.B_ID.eq(B.ID))
        )
      )))
      .from(B)
      .where(B.A_ID.eq(A.ID))
    ).as("list_of_b")
  )
  .from(A)
  .fetch();
```

The usual static import is assumed:

```java
import static ord.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Since jOOQ is all about [dynamic SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/), chances are, you can automate some of the nesting with dynamic SQL.

All of the above also works with `JSONB` in PostgreSQL, just use [`jsonbArrayAgg()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#jsonbArrayAgg(org.jooq.Field)) and [`jsonbObject()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#jsonbObject(org.jooq.JSONEntry...)) instead.

Note that `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` aggregates empty sets into `NULL`, not into an empty `[]`. [If that's a problem, use `COALESCE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932476/521799)

#### Mapping the above into POJOs

If you have Jackson or Gson on your classpath, you can now just write [`fetchInto(APojo.class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchInto(java.lang.Class)) at the end to map the resulting JSON tree. But you're probably just going to map the POJOs back into JSON again using either Jackson or Gson, so from a high level, I don't think you get a lot of value out of this step.

#### The jOOQ 3.15 approach to nesting collections

Starting from jOOQ 3.15, a number of improvements to type safe mapping and nesting collections will be implemented

- [#3884](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3884) `MULTISET` and `ARRAY` constructor from subquery support (finally!)
- [#7100](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7100) Ad-hoc `Field` data type conversion convenience
- [#11804](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11804) Type safe mapping of `Record[N]` types to constructor references
- [#11812](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11812) Support for nested `ROW` expressions in projections

With all of the above, in case you really *need* your POJO intermediary step (and assuming you will have the necessary "immutable constructors" on your POJOs, e.g. like canonical record constructors in Java 16+). E.g.

```java
record EPojo (String name) {}
record DPojo (String name, EPojo[] listOfE) {}
record CPojo (String name, DPojo[] listOfD) {}
record BPojo (String name, CPojo[] listOfC) {}
record APojo (String name, BPojo[] listOfB) {}
```

In that case, you will be able to write something like this:

```java
ctx
  .select(A.NAME, array(
     select(row(B.NAME, array(
       select(row(C.NAME, array(
         select(row(D.NAME, array(
           select(row(E.NAME).mapping(EPojo::new))
           .from(E)
           .where(E.D_ID.eq(D.ID))
         )).mapping(DPojo::new))
         .from(D)
         .where(D.C_ID.eq(C.ID))
       )).mapping(CPojo::new))
       .from(C)
       .where(C.B_ID.eq(B.ID))
     )).mapping(BPojo::new))
     .from(B)
     .where(B.A_ID.eq(A.ID))
  )
  .from(A)
  .fetch(Records.mapping(APojo::new));
```

If you prefer `List<SomePojo>` over `SomePojo[]`, then you'd just have to use the new ad-hoc conversion from arrays to list on the array expressions, e.g.

```java
array(select(...)).convertFrom(Arrays::asList)
```

I'll update this part of the answer, once the API has stabilised.

#### Further outlook

Since these types of "nested collection joins" will become very common in jOOQ, irrespective of whether SQL collections are nested in SQL, or JSON collections, or XML collections, future versions of jOOQ will probably offer a more convenient syntax, [similar to the implicit join syntax for ordinary to-one joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/).

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder for quick response, I am just trying to avoid the nested select queries.

Comment: @Hrishi: Why would you want to avoid them?

Comment: I think joining table is more optimised way then nested sub queries in ```select``` as ```fields``` to fetch the data because sub queries in ```select``` as ```fields``` get executed as many times as no. of records fetched by parent query.

Comment: @Hrishi: Well, are you going to dump the entire data set from the database in hierarchical form? In that case, yes, hash joins (`O(N)`) will outperform the nested aggregations (`O(A * log B * log C * log D * log E)` at best, polynomial, i.e. `O(N^5)` at worst, though unlikely). It might still be OK, depending on the data set size, especially depending on the subset sizes of each nested collection. But if you're fetching this data only for a small data set (e.g. with some filter on `A` at the top level, then you'll be fine (you'd be getting nested loop joins anyway).

Comment: Correct, for small datasets it will work fine. I am not going to dump the whole data set. It is going to fetch single record at first 2 levels but from 3rd level it may be 50-100 on 3rd level itself and same on 4th and 5th for each record on 3rd level.

Thanks for the solutions!